# Internal server error:after dist path refresh

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

After the dist path refresh i am getting the internal server error.

I have created dist folder by running the command

```
ng build -- prod /ctMap/CTAngular4/dist/
```

after navigating this URL

```
https://XXXXXXXX/ctMap/CTAngular4/dist/dashboard
```

i am able to see  page. here i am loading a google map, with current location, now if refresh the page getting the internal server error and  while working on local above the map i am displaying the current location , in localhost its working fine, after uploading to the server the dist folder only the map i am able to see, not the current location.why?  the changes in behavior  between localhost and server.

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: You need configure the .htaccess file in server..check the angular documentation